# Hashing Plaid Request Body Webhook

Tags: python, jwt, plaid

I am trying to verify a webhook sent from Plaid's [API](https://plaid.com/docs/#webhook-verification). Every webhook request is sent with a 'plaid-verification' header which is a JSON Web Token.

The steps required to validate are:

1. Extract JWT from request header

`signed_jwt = eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZjNTUxNmUxLTkyZGMtNDc5ZS1hOGZmLTVhNTE5OTJlMDAwMSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTA4ODcwMDEsInJlcXVlc3RfYm9keV9zaGEyNTYiOiJiNjNhMDdiNTQ3YjAwZjk5MjU0N2Y2YmJjOGQ5YWNjNjFhOGNjZWUxMzhiYzgyZjQ0YTZiYWEwOTY4M2E1ZDBmIn0.OOKvIihgqCj7Qrb2bmz7T3t7uK-0JyjiEqL2s1kWeJBM4MMmjaHKK8GmU_z91QolBWMzvPgs718EElY-rE3cwQ`

2. Extract JWT header value without validating the signature, which looks like this:

```
    {
      "alg": "ES256",
      "kid": "6c5516e1-92dc-479e-a8ff-5a51992e0001",
      "typ": "JWT"
    }
```

3. Extract the `kid` and POST to `/webhook_verification_key/get`

```
    POST /webhook_verification_key/get
    {
        "client_id": "MY_CLIENT_ID"
        "secret": "MY_SECRET_ID"
        "key_id": "6c5516e1-92dc-479e-a8ff-5a51992e0001"
    }
```

The response is:

```
{
  "key": {
    "alg": "ES256",
    "created_at": 1560466143,
    "crv": "P-256",
    "expired_at": null,
    "kid": "6c5516e1-92dc-479e-a8ff-5a51992e0001",
    "kty": "EC",
    "use": "sig",
    "x": "35lvC8uz2QrWpQJ3TUH8t9o9DURMp7ydU518RKDl20k",
    "y": "I8BuXB2bvxelzJAd7OKhd-ZwjCst05Fx47Mb_0ugros"
  },
  "request_id": "HvfCtrDLG1ihcp7"
}
```

4. Interpret `key` as a JSON Web Key, validate that the signature of the JSON Web Key is valid, and extract the payload (using jose python library)

```
claims = jwt.decode(signed_jwt, key, algorithms=['ES256'])

claims = {
             "iat": 1590887001, 
             "request_body_sha256": "b63a07b547b00f992547f6bbc8d9acc61a8ccee138bc82f44a6baa09683a5d0f"
         }
```

5. Compute the SHA-256 of the request body and ensure that it matches `claims['request_body_sha256']`:

Body is in a file body.json

```
{
    "error": null,
    "item_id": "yxQbxDjnD8hr69pKbQpbcKeVn3GL9QuyA7NV3",
    "new_transactions": 390,
    "webhook_code": "HISTORICAL_UPDATE",
    "webhook_type": "TRANSACTIONS"
}
```

Compute SHA-256 of body.json

```
f = open('body.json')
body = json.load(f)
f.close()

m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(json.dumps(body).encode())
body_hash = m.hexdigest()
print(body_hash)

body_hash = 'efbb5274864518f7eb3834125d9bcdb95fb03066d3d1bed3ebcc6163d8dc3579'
```

The body hash in the example above does not equal the body hash received from Plaid. There's 2 possible problems here:

1. Plaid isn't sending the correct body hash (unlikely)
2. The hash method I'm using to hash the body is not the same as Plaid's method

Is there something I'm missing here? Perhaps the request body is encoded differently on my end? I'm using Node.js and Express in production but I made a Python script to follow the method Plaid outlined [here](https://support.plaid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041410794), but I'm still not getting the correct hash. I'm honestly out of ideas.

Comment: This simple example is more informative and easier to follow than the plaid docs!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with whitespace.  If you modify body.json to have 2 spaces per ‘tab’ on each new line, it will generate the right hash.

Answer (score 9):

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62143991/2745495) is right. I ran into the same issue recently, and it does indeed appear that Plaid hashes their body based on a tab spacing of 2. You can use

```
JSON.stringify(body, null, 2)
```

to make it work:

```
const happyBody = JSON.stringify(body, null, 2);
const body_hash = crypto
  .createHash("sha256")
  .update(happyBody)
  .digest("hex");
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Bonus: You *could* use `JSON.stringify(object, replacer, space)` to beautify the JSON. An integer for the last argument will determine how many spaces to use, but you could replace that with something like `"/t"` if you wanted tabs instead:

```
JSON.stringify(someObject, null, "\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m.update(json.dumps(body, indent=2).encode())
```